Websocket keep disconecting
I'm working on a project where I'm using Socket.IO to establish a low-latency connection between a server and a Raspberry Pi 5. The Pi is both a client and hosts another relay server. The connection works for a while but then enters a disconnection loop.
Here is the behavior:
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 5.01 seconds
INFO:geventwebsocket.handler:192.168.1.103 - - [2024-08-20 10:26:38] "GET /socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4&sid=BlFj5QtkLH1eZUyYAAAF&t=1724145973.7493463 HTTP/1.1" 200 157 25.001898
DEBUG:geventwebsocket.handler:Initializing WebSocket
DEBUG:geventwebsocket.handler:Validating WebSocket request
DEBUG:geventwebsocket.handler:Can only upgrade connection if using GET method.
INFO:geventwebsocket.handler:192.168.1.103 - - [2024-08-20 10:26:38] "POST /socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=4&sid=BlFj5QtkLH1eZUyYAAAF HTTP/1.1" 200 143 0.000526
DEBUG:geventwebsocket.handler:Initializing WebSocket
DEBUG:geventwebsocket.handler:Validating WebSocket request
Connection failed, new attempt in 5.46 seconds
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 5.46 seconds
Connection failed, new attempt in 4.57 seconds
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 4.57 seconds
Received packet PING data 
INFO:engineio.client:Received packet PING data 
Sending packet PONG data 
INFO:engineio.client:Sending packet PONG data 
Connection failed, new attempt in 4.92 seconds
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 4.92 seconds
Connection failed, new attempt in 5.00 seconds
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 5.00 seconds
Connection failed, new attempt in 4.62 seconds
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 4.62 seconds
....
INFO:socketio.client:Connection failed, new attempt in 5.04 seconds
Received packet PING data 
INFO:engineio.client:Received packet PING data 
Sending packet PONG data 
INFO:engineio.client:Sending packet PONG data 
WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
WARNING:engineio.client:WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
Waiting for write loop task to end
INFO:engineio.client:Waiting for write loop task to end
Exiting write loop task
INFO:engineio.client:Exiting write loop task
Engine.IO connection dropped
INFO:socketio.client:Engine.IO connection dropped
2024-08-20 10:29:18,487 INFO: Disconnected from external server
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): [Url hidden for security]
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: [Url hidden for security] HTTP/1.1" 200 20
INFO:__main__:Disconnected from external server
2024-08-20 10:29:18,984 INFO: Already connected to external server. Skipping reconnection.

Here is how I handle connection and reconnection:
def connect_to_external_server():
    global failure_count
    connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            if not sio.connected:
                logger.info(f"Connecting to external server at {EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL}...")
                sio.connect(EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL, transports=['websocket'])
                connected = True
                logger.info("Successfully connected to external server.")
            else:
                logger.info("Already connected to external server. Skipping reconnection.")
                connected = True
        except socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            logger.error(f"Connection to external server failed: {e}. Retrying...")
            failure_count += 1
            if failure_count >= max_failures:
                logger.error(f"Maximum connection failures reached. Restarting script...")
                os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
            sleep_time = min(30, 5 * 2 ** (failure_count - 1)) + random.uniform(0, 1)
            logger.info(f"Retrying in {sleep_time} seconds...")
            time.sleep(sleep_time)


# Event handlers for the external server
@sio.event
def connect():
    logger.info('Connected to external server')

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    logger.info('Disconnected from external server')
    connect_to_external_server()

Has anyone experienced similar issues or can provide insights into why this disconnection loop might be happening? Any suggestions for improving the connection stability would be appreciated.
I try to restart the script automatically which seems to work, but it is not the solution that I want because I need this to handle alot of requests.
